# Rebuild a Hive table with different definitions

Tags: mysql, hive, alter-table, alter, presto

I want to build an automatic system to help me map Hive tables.
I have an SQL table with meta data: tableID, fieldName, field Type, description, lastUpdated.
I want to update automatically my tables -

```
where lastUpdate=CURDATE() - INTERVAL '1' DAY
```

But I don't have an indication on what change was made - it can be a new column in the table, and it can be a column name that was changed, or even a description update.
Is there a way to "define" a table all over again when it already exists? That all the changes I want to make will be executed at once (all change types)?

for instance - I have a table that was defined like this:

```
create external table IF NOT EXISTS tableA (`a` string, `b` int, `c` int) PARTITIONED BY (dt date) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' STORED AS TEXTFILE LOCATION 'File/Path';
```

And the change was that column "b" type is now "string". Is there a (generic) update/alter query that I can write:

```
*SomeCommand* tableA (`a` string, `b` string, `c` int)
```

and my column will be updated?

Same if I have a new column - d, type: float.

```
*SomeCommand* tableA (`a` string, `b` string, `c` int, `d` float)
```

I need one command that can contain these options, please. Or - if you have another good idea n how to do this, I will really appreciate it...

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ALTER TABLE REPLACE COLUMNS`. It does exactly what you asked,

It will replace all the columns at once. See https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-Add/ReplaceColumns

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful!